# How to compare two Data.Frames to add missing data

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rbind

I'm new to coding and trying to write a loop. I've tried various ways but still haven't found a solution.

Using the example data shown below, I want my loop to:

1. Look at S$ID.
2. Find all S$ID that match and: 
            A1) Compare all Label_Chr recorded for that ID with the Master_DataFrame$Label_Chr 
            A2) Identify all those that are missing.
            A3) For those that are missing add a new row to Data.Frame S, filled with: The Bird_ID, Missing Label_Chr and Columns Duration and Count as 0's.
3. Keep looping until all matched groups are complete

```
Below are examples of the data:     
----------------------------------
Data.Frame S
*ID*                       *Label_Chr*     *Duration*   *Count*
OP_Pen12_R_30mins               Walk.           3.310        1
OP_Pen12_R_30mins               Run.            0.250        1
OP_Pen12_R_30mins               Talk.           1.960        1
OP_Pen12_R_Immediate            Sit.            1.830        1
OP_Pen12_R_Immediate            Talk.           3.850        2

-------------------------------------
Master_DataFrame
*Label_Chr*.     *Duration*  *Count*
Walk.                 0         0
Run                   0         0
Sit                   0         0
Talk                  0         0
----------------------------------

The end S data frame would look like this: 
*ID*                       *Label_Chr*     *Duration*   *Count*
OP_Pen12_R_30mins               Walk.           3.310        1
OP_Pen12_R_30mins               Run.            0.250        1
OP_Pen12_R_30mins               Talk.           1.960        1
OP_Pen12_R_30mins               Sit.            0            0

OP_Pen12_R_Immediate            Sit.            1.830        1
OP_Pen12_R_Immediate            Talk.           3.850        2
OP_Pen12_R_Immediate            Walk.           0            0
OP_Pen12_R_Immediate            Run.            0            0
```

I've tried various things such as:

```
k <- 1
for(i in 1:length(S))
  for (ii in 1:length(MasterBehaviours))
  {Bird_Comparison <- strcmp(S[i,1], S[i+1,1])
  Behaviour_Comparison <- strcmp(S[i,3], MasterBehaviours[ii+1,1]) }
if(Bird_Comparison == TRUE & Behaviour_Comparison == FALSE) # {print(Bird_Comparison) 
{ZZ <- rbind(S, MasterBehaviours[1+k,1])}
print(ZZ)}
```

And also:

```
for(i in 1:length(S[,]))
{x <- S[i,1]
y <- S[i+1,1]
labelCheck <- (x==y)}
if(labelCheck == TRUE)
{Behaviour_Comparison <- strcmp(S[i+1,3], MasterBehaviours[1+k,1])}
if (Behaviour_Comparison == FALSE)
{rbind(S, MasterBehaviours[1+k,1])
  print(S)}
```

Not much happens with the above code. For the first attempt, ZZ isn't created, I get this:

> Error in print(ZZ) : object 'ZZ' not found

And for the second block: I get two errors:

> Error in if (labelCheck == TRUE) {
>
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: What happens with the code you are showing? What output do you get, and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: Not much happens with the above code. 

For the first block: ZZ isn't created and I get error: Error in print(ZZ) : object 'ZZ' not found

And for the second block: I get two errors: 
Error in if (labelCheck == TRUE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
and
Error: object 'Behaviour_Comparison' not found

Initially I'm not sure if my first line of the loop is correct. My data frame has 10 rows and I want it to look at each line individually but I'm not sure whether 'i' should = 10L, or 1L .. which is probably a major issue in itself